# How do I find the median in the DataFrame column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, median

df['diff']

1. 23:59:01
2. 23:59:13
3. 23:59:17
4. 23:59:27
5. 23:59:52

hh-mm-ss data is obtained after calculating the difference between sessions via TimesDelta.
Converted time into seconds and found the median. How do I find the median in hh-mm-ss format?

Answer (score 0):

The `diff` column need to be converted to numerical seconds.

```
import pandas as pd
def time2sec(t):
 (h, m, s) = t.split(':')
 return int(h) * 3600 + int(m) * 60 + int(s)

df = pd.DataFrame(['23:59:01','23:59:13','23:59:17','23:59:27','23:59:52'],columns=['diff'])
df['diff_sec'] = df['diff'].map(time2sec)
print(df)
median = df['diff_sec'].median()
print('median :',median)
```

```
       diff  diff_sec
0  23:59:01     86341
1  23:59:13     86353
2  23:59:17     86357
3  23:59:27     86367
4  23:59:52     86392
86357.0
```

Answer (score 0):

If your data is already in Timedelta format as you mentioned, you can just use [`df.median()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.median.html) to get the median of the series.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
pd.to_timedelta(df['diff']).median()
```

[`pd.to_timedelta`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_timedelta.html) converts the date string to Timedelta.  Then, we can use [`Series.median()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.median.html) to get the median.

**Result**:

```
Timedelta('0 days 23:59:17')
```